# What's the difference between the scope of a function and a class

Tags: c++, function, class

I used `ros` and tried to put definitions of subscribers and servers into function outside. Then the callback didn't run. The `spin()` function didn't work. But I often see others put definitions of servers into a class and callback will work. So what makes the difference between the two scenes?

This will work

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{

  ros::init(argc, argv, "cood_tran");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;

    std::cout << "coodTran" << std::endl;
  target_obj = "None";
  ros::param::get("target", target_obj);

  ros::Subscriber ros_coord_pixel_sub =
  nh.subscribe("/darknet_ros/bounding_boxes", 1, darknetCallback);

  ros::Subscriber point_cloud_sub =
  nh.subscribe("camera/depth_registered/points", 1, pointCouldCallback);///camera/depth_registered/points  /camera/depth_registered/points<->color_optical

  ros::ServiceServer location_server =
  nh.advertiseService("location_srv", location);


  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}
```

This won't work

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{

  ros::init(argc, argv, "cood_tran");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  coodTran(nh);


  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}

void coodTran(ros::NodeHandle nh)
{

  std::cout << "coodTran" << std::endl;
  target_obj = "None";
  ros::param::get("target", target_obj);

  ros::Subscriber ros_coord_pixel_sub =
  nh.subscribe("/darknet_ros/bounding_boxes", 1, darknetCallback);

  ros::Subscriber point_cloud_sub =
  nh.subscribe("camera/depth_registered/points", 1, pointCouldCallback);///camera/depth_registered/points  /camera/depth_registered/points<->color_optical

  ros::ServiceServer location_server =
  nh.advertiseService("location_srv", location);

}
```

This will work:

```
#include <darknet_ros/YoloObjectDetector.hpp>
#include <ros/ros.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  ros::init(argc, argv, "darknet_ros");
  ros::NodeHandle nodeHandle("~");

  darknet_ros::YoloObjectDetector yoloObjectDetector(nodeHandle);

  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: [scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope)

Comment: I don't understand this question. The scope of a function and a class have nothing in common. The only connection I can see is that you declare things in both of them and they're delimited by curly braces. I also don't see the connection between the code shown and the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

In the second fragment you're passing NodeHandle by value. So, in the coodTran you're changing a copy of the original nh.
Try passing it by reference like this:

```
    void coodTran(ros::NodeHandle& nh) {
       nh.sunscribe();
    }
```

Or pass pointer to the original object:

```
    void coodTran(ros::NodeHandle* nh) {
       nh->sunscribe();
    }
```

Or create node in the function and return handle:

```
    ros::NodeHandle coodTran() {
        ros::NodeHandle nh;
        nh->sunscribe();
        return nh;
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I think the reason may be that the definition of subscribe is in function out of the main function.

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? I mean, which variant have you tried and how did it fail?